# How to remap arrow keys in Vim in insert mode?

Tags: vim

When I am in insert mode I want to use the keys <kbd>h</kbd>, <kbd>j</kbd>, <kbd>k</kbd> and <kbd>l</kbd> to behave as the arrow keys.

I want to achieve this by holding the <kbd>ctrl</kbd> key and then <kbd>ctrl + k</kbd> would move the line upwards in insert mode. Since these four keys are already mapped to move the lines when not in insert mode, how can I achieve this behavior when I am in insert mode?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `imap` for that like this:

```
inoremap <C-h> <Left>
inoremap <C-j> <Down>
inoremap <C-k> <Up>
inoremap <C-l> <Right>
```